# Twitter Streaming API in JS using Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: javascript, twitter, windows-phone-8.1

I've recently set out on the quest of making a Twitter app for the Lumia 521 that isn't;

1. Slow (this hardware requires fine-grained performance driven code)
2. Bandwidth eating
3. Lastly, Not WP8.1 odd style looking.

Regardless, I've gotten far on it. Learned how to hand-construct OAuth requests, then switch to utilizing jsOAuth anyways, but the big gotcha right now is Streaming. I've seen *tons* of stuff on C# code, but I don't "speak" C#.

I've read docs on XHR addons by MS, but that hasn't gotten me anywhere, and googling leads me to no avail. (Big problem for the WP community it would seem)

Anyways, any pointers on methods or things I could use besides creating a quick n' dirty socket.io based router to do this would be awesome!

(could `ms-stream` possibly be used as a xhr.responeType?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, my solution was to utilize jsOAuth & [Oboe.js](http://oboejs.com/)

I did this, like so:

Replace all the xhr stuff with:

```
            oboe({
                url: url + '',
                method: method,
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'OAuth ' + toHeaderString(headerParams),
                    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
                },
                body: query
            })
                .fail(failure)
                .done(success);
```

Then call it: requestStream

and copy get to getStream to use that new function name!